# Is the Haskell type class 'Real' a misnomer?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

I am trying to understand the [numeric type class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num) hierarchy in Haskell. The basic numeric type is

```
class Num a where
...
```

As a side note, according to some of my sources (slides), it should actually be

```
class Eq a => Num a where
...
```

but I cannot find this in the Prelude.

Now, I am interested in the `Real` type class

```
class (Num a, Ord a) => Real a where
  -- the rational equivalent of its real argument with full precision
  toRational :: a -> Rational
```

I guess that `Real` refers to the fact that types that are instances of `Real` are not complex. But my understanding of a `Real` number from Mathematics is that it can be *Rational* and *Irrational*, so there is no equivalent of `toRational` for all of them. Of course, irrational numbers can't be used in computers anyways...

Thanks!

Comment: `Num` requiring `Eq` is in the Haskell report (the specification), but it's not included in GHC because it's a seriously annoying requirement. `Num` is generally regarded as one of the cruftier classes in Haskell: purescript's equivalent is a good example of what a redesign might look like.

Comment: The change of Num no longer requiring Eq appears to have been made in the GHC 7.4 release: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/release-7-4-1.html

Comment: You say "irrational numbers can't be used in computers"; I say [huh?](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cyclotomic) [what?](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers-3000.2.0.2/docs/Data-Number-CReal.html)

Comment: Non-computable numbers can’t (really) be used by computers. Not all irrational numbers are non-computable though. A lot of the irrational numbers you come across in practical applications (like pi and e) are computable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the name `Real` is a rather misleading name for the class of types that can be converted to a rational.

Indeed, we have instances like `Real Integer`, `Real IntPtr`, `Real CBool` which can be very surprising.

The standard numeric classes are generally regarded as being a bit weird, both in their names and in their overall design.

Answer (score 5):

In general, Haskell's number classes are a bit of a mess. They're defined in a way that makes it convenient and easy to use the basic number types like `Int`, `Integer`, `Double`, etc. But when you start wanting more advanced kinds of numbers... they don't always make a lot of sense.

---

Regarding `Num`: This is interesting. Both the Haskell '98 and Haskell 2010 Report demand that

```
class (Eq a, Show a) => Num a
```

If you look at the documentation for `base-4.0.0.0`, you find this is the case:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.0.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#7

However, at some point the `base` package was changed such that `Num` now has no superclasses (contradicting the Report). So your slides aren't wrong; it *used* to be defined that way, but it got changed at some point. If you dig far enough, there's probably a ticket or a wiki page about this.

---

Regarding `Real`... yes, the name is rather misleading. I'm also not really sure why it's different than `RealFrac`, which is *also* about conversions from a number to various ratios or integers.

---

If this kind of thing interests you, there are various "alternative Prelude" libraries out there (e.g., "classy Prelude", "numeric Prelude") which replace the standard Prelude with something hopefully a little bit more sensible. It turns out it's surprisingly hard to do this really well — which is why the official spec hasn't really changed much. Nobody has suggested anything conclusively better.

Comment: `Real` **is** saying, basically, that all representable values have to be rational. I think you're talking about `Fractional` with its `fromRational` method, but `Real` actually has `toRational`.

Comment: Your comparison to `fromInteger` does not seem right to me as that converts in the other direction. If I have a type that represents computable reals and I want that to implement `Real`, my implementation of `toRational` must either break contract by rounding irrational numbers with some fixed precision (note that the docs say "full precision") or be partial.

Comment: Though on second thought, implementations of `fromInteger` can be partial too (not every `Integer` can be represented as an `Int` for example - or a `Double` for that matter), so a comparison would actually make sense to justify a `toRational` implementation that diverges on irrational numbers.

Comment: @sepp2k the problem is that [almost all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_all) real numbers are irrational. It's not just that very big numbers don't allow `toRational` anymore, but basically _any_ number you pull from a typical distribution of reals can't be converted to rational without rounding.

Comment: @leftaroundabout You're right. I only realised at the end of the paragraph. I've taken that part out now.